# Python regex issue with not matching \.\s

Tags: python, python-re

I have a large data set with many groups to match. I have managed to match them all apart from two combinations which don't match. And it makes no sense to me why every other group would match but these. At first it looked like any sequence with a **period-space-character** was the issue, but then I managed to match other groups with this sequence. I am reading a file and then writing the extracted groups to a new file using if statements. The RegEx issue exists without the if statement part of the code too.

I have **highlighted** the line items that are the issue to resolve.

Any help appreciated.

- `(X.\d{1,3}\.\sY.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}?$) # match NOT found X-75. Y-36.6`
- `(X.\d{1,3}\.\sY.\d{1,3}\.$) # match NOT found X-55. Y-38.`

I have also tried adding a \s at the end

- `(X.\d{1,3}\.\sY.\d{1,3}\.\s$)`

read file:

```
G0 X-69.4 Y-33.8
G43 Z15. H1
Z5.
G98 G81 X-69.4 Y-33.8 Z-27. R5. F126.
X-68.
X-66.6
X-65.2
X-63.8
X-62.4
X-61.
X-58.4 Y-35.2
X-59.6
X-61.
X-62.4
X-63.8
X-65.2
X-66.6
X-68.
X-69.4
X-70.8
X-72.2
**X-75. Y-36.6**
X-73.6
X-72.2
X-70.8
X-69.4
X-68.
X-66.6
X-65.2
X-63.8
X-62.4
X-61.
X-59.6
X-58.4
X-57.
**X-55. Y-38.**
```

Write file:

```
X-69.4 Y-33.8
Z-27 
Z0 

X-69.4 Y-33.8 
Z-27. 
Z0 

X-68.

Z-27 
Z0 

X-66.6
Z-27 
Z0 

X-65.2
Z-27 
Z0 

X-63.8
Z-27 
Z0 

X-62.4
Z-27 
Z0 

X-61.

Z-27 
Z0 

X-58.4 Y-35.2
Z-27 
Z0 

X-59.6
Z-27 
Z0 

X-61.

Z-27 
Z0 

X-62.4
Z-27 
Z0 

X-63.8
Z-27 
Z0 

X-65.2
Z-27 
Z0 

X-66.6
Z-27 
Z0 

X-68.

Z-27 
Z0 

X-69.4
Z-27 
Z0 

X-70.8
Z-27 
Z0 

X-72.2
Z-27 
Z0 

**X-75.** 
Z-27 
Z0 

X-73.6
Z-27 
Z0 

X-72.2
Z-27 
Z0 

X-70.8
Z-27 
Z0 

X-69.4
Z-27 
Z0 

X-68.

Z-27 
Z0 

X-66.6
Z-27 
Z0 

X-65.2
Z-27 
Z0 

X-63.8
Z-27 
Z0 

X-62.4
Z-27 
Z0 

X-61.

Z-27 
Z0 

X-59.6
Z-27 
Z0 

X-58.4
Z-27 
Z0 

X-57.

Z-27 
Z0 

**X-55.**
Z-27 
Z0
```

Code

```
with open(fileToRead, 'r') as readFile:
    with open(fileToWrite, 'w') as writeFile:
        fileContents = readFile.read()
        pattern1 = re.compile(
            r'(X.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}?\sY.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}?\s)(Z.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}?\s)|(X.\d{1,3}\.\sY.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}?\s)(Z.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}?\s)|(X.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}?\sY.\d{1,3}\.\s)(Z.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}?\s)|'
            r'(X.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}?\sY.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}?\s)(Z.\d{1,3}\.\s)|(X.\d{1,3}\.\s)|(X.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$)|(X.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}?\sY.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}?$)|(X.\d{1,3}\.\sY.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}?$)|'
            r'(X.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}?\sY.\d{1,3}\.$)|(X.\d{1,3}\.\s^Y.\d{1,3}\.$)', re.M)

        linePrefix = ''
        lineSuffix1 = '\n'
        lineSuffix2 = ''
        lineSuffix3 = '\nZ0 \n\n'
        
        for match in matches1:
            count = count + 1
            if match.group(1):
                format1 = linePrefix.__add__(str(match.group(1))).__add__(lineSuffix1).__add__(linePrefix).__add__(
                    str(match.group(2))).__add__(lineSuffix2).__add__(lineSuffix3)
                print(format1)
                writeFile.write(format1)
            elif match.group(3):
                format2 = linePrefix.__add__(str(match.group(3))).__add__(lineSuffix1).__add__(linePrefix).__add__(str(match.group(4))).__add__(lineSuffix2).__add__(lineSuffix3)
                print(format2)
                writeFile.write(format2)
            elif match.group(5):
                format3 = linePrefix.__add__(str(match.group(5))).__add__(lineSuffix1).__add__(linePrefix).__add__(str(match.group(6))).__add__(lineSuffix2).__add__(lineSuffix3)
                print(format3)
                writeFile.write(format3)
            elif match.group(7):
                format4 = linePrefix.__add__(str(match.group(7))).__add__(lineSuffix1).__add__(linePrefix).__add__(str(match.group(8))).__add__(lineSuffix2).__add__(lineSuffix3)
                print(format4)
                writeFile.write(format4)
            elif match.group(9):
                format5 = linePrefix.__add__(str(match.group(9))).__add__(lineSuffix1).__add__(linePrefix).__add__('Z-27 ').__add__(lineSuffix2).__add__(lineSuffix3)
                print(format5)
                writeFile.write(format5)
            elif match.group(10):
                format6 = linePrefix.__add__(str(match.group(10))).__add__(lineSuffix1).__add__(linePrefix).__add__('Z-27 ').__add__(lineSuffix2).__add__(lineSuffix3)
                print(format6)
                writeFile.write(format6)
            elif match.group(11):
                format7 = linePrefix.__add__(str(match.group(11))).__add__(lineSuffix1).__add__(linePrefix).__add__('Z-27 ').__add__(lineSuffix2).__add__(lineSuffix3)
                print(format7)
                writeFile.write(format7)
            elif match.group(12):
                format8 = linePrefix.__add__(str(match.group(12))).__add__(lineSuffix1).__add__(linePrefix).__add__('Z-27 ').__add__(lineSuffix2).__add__(lineSuffix3)
                print(format8)
                writeFile.write(format8)
            elif match.group(13):
                format9 = linePrefix.__add__(str(match.group(13))).__add__(lineSuffix1).__add__(linePrefix).__add__('Z-27 ').__add__(lineSuffix2).__add__(lineSuffix3)
                print(format9)
                writeFile.write(format9)
            elif match.group(14):
                format10 = linePrefix.__add__(str(match.group(14))).__add__(lineSuffix1).__add__(linePrefix).__add__('Z-27 ').__add__(lineSuffix2).__add__(lineSuffix3)
                print(format10)
                writeFile.write(format10)

            print('\nPATTERN', count, ':\n')
```

Comment: Could you give an example of a single regex and a single string which does not match but you expect it to?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. That regex matches all three lines at the end of the example text and the two other lines below, which start with `X-55.`. Please provide a [mre]. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: Hmmm. How odd. I will double check and then if I am still getting the same issue I will show in more detail what is going on.

Comment: And thanks for the welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain about your intention, so you can clarify what you want. But I did try this on an online regex tester and it works fine.

`.*(X-\d{1,3}\.\d?\sY-\d{1,3}\.\d?).*`

Comment: I have tried to add more context to the question now. If you could help that would be ace.

Comment: The regex you have in progress is too large for me to try to understand. You should write an ordinary sentence or two about what you're trying to do. What is the input? What is the expected output? Which cases are failing and why do you suspect that? Write this info as sentences.